# React Native: I am able to print my data on my console, but how do i display the data on my React Native app screen?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

```
const getVote =() =>{
  db.collection('PARLIMEN').doc(auth.currentUser?.email).get()
  .then((doc)=>{
    if (doc.exists){
      console.log("document data: ", doc.data());

    }
    else{
      console.log('document is empty');

    }
  })
  .catch(error=>{
    console.log('firebase eror:'+error)
  })
}
```

I am able to get the data to display on my console, but i do not know how to display the same data on the application screen. Any help/suggestions on this?

[firestore data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEUZm.png)
[data displayed on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZLnS.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `useState` to store your data. Use `useEffect` to trigger your query when the page loads, or invoke the `getVote()` function wherever you desire. However, in that case you'd need to extract it out of the useEffect, and wrap it in a `useCallback()`.

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
const getVote = () => {
  db.collection('PARLIMEN').doc(auth.currentUser?.email).get()
  .then((doc)=>{
    if (!doc.exists) return
    console.log("document data: ", doc.data());
    setData(() => doc.data()) // <--- here you set the data state
  })
  .catch(console.error)
}
getVote();
},[auth, db])

return (
  <View>
  <Text>
  {data && JSON.stringify(data)}
  </Text>
  </View>
)
```

Comment: Remember that divs are not supported in react native

Comment: Just change it to `View`

Answer (score -1):

Using React native you can show the data on the app screen using the `Text` component.

```js
const [doc, setDoc] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
  const getVote = async () =>{
    const doc = await db.collection('PARLIMEN').doc(auth.currentUser?.email).get()
  
    if (doc.exists){
      setDoc(doc.data())
    }
    else{
      console.log('document is empty')
    }
  })
}
}, [])

return (
  <View>
    <Text>
      {data && JSON.stringify(data)}
    </Text>
  </View>
)
```